# Does natural parameter of exponential family need the constant or sign?

Tags: statistics, exponential-function, gamma-distribution

For instance the exponential form of gamma distribution is $e^{(\alpha -1)\ln{x}-\beta x+ (something \ about \ only \ \alpha \ and \ \beta) }$, the natural parameters given on wikipedia are $(\alpha -1)$ and $-\beta$, but why not $\beta $ for the second one. Do constants&sign not affect sufficient statistics and natural parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if i get ur question right u are wondering if the form of the parameters affect the distribution? The distributions have a specific form and u can't change it. If u changes -b to b then  $e^{4lnx−3x+(something about only α and β)}$ would belong to the distribution $Gamma(5,-3)$ but in reality it belongs to $Gamma(5,3)$ so yes it is essential that u keep the forms as they are. Of course there are transformations in every distributions formula so u can do different mathematical approaches but they are used intact.

Comment: But then how to we determine the natural parameter& sufficient statistics if we do know that it is a gamma? I am just wondering why is it -$\beta$ at the begining

Comment: In some cases u study a characteristic of a population knowing which distribution follows making assumptions knowing it. In other cases u study a characteristic without knowing the distribution, trying to make one with properties that corresponds to the population. In any case for, every known distribution there are some variables that characterize it. Ex:$Gamma(a,b)$,$Νormal(μ,σ)$,$Exp(θ)$ if u know in which one distribution family a population belongs (gamma family for example), by studying ur sample u can find the (a,b) of the specific gamma the sample belongs.